# how to count record in a range of date along with its criteria

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have two databases which are:

```
Reservation
------------------------------------------------
| ID | RoomID | RoomName | BookingDate         |
|-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 77     | Gold     | 2017-12-05 00:00:00 |
| 2  | 88     | Crystal  | 2017-12-11 00:00:00 |
| 3  | 88     | Crystal  | 2017-12-20 00:00:00 |
| 4  | 99     | Diamond  | 2017-12-01 00:00:00 |
| 5  | 77     | Gold     | 2017-12-04 00:00:00 |
| 6  | 77     | Gold     | 2017-12-15 00:00:00 |
-------------------------------------------------

Room
-----------------
| ID | RoomName |
-----------------
| 77 | Gold     |
| 88 | Crystal  |
| 99 | Diamond  |
-----------------
```

I tried to count the number of record of the room within the range of the date. The output was suppose to be:

> ```
> ------------------------------------------------------
> | Date                    | Gold | Crystal | Diamond | 
> ------------------------------------------------------
> | 1.12.2017 - 3.12.2017   |  0   |    0    |   1     |
> | 4.12.2017 - 10.12.2017  |  2   |    0    |   0     |
> | 11.12.2017 - 17.12.2017 |  1   |    1    |   0     |
> | 18.12.2017 - 24.12.2017 |  0   |    1    |   0     |
> | 25.12.2017 - 31.12.2017 |  0   |    0    |   0     |
> ------------------------------------------------------
> ```

My coding is as follow:

```
<table>
<tr><th> Date </th>
    <?php
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Room", $con);
     while($record = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>
    <td> <?php echo $record['RoomName']?> </td>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
</tr>
<tr> <td>
     <?php
    $week = date("W", strtotime($_GET['Year'] . "-" . $_GET['Month'] ."-01")); // weeknumber of first day of month
    $startRange = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_GET['Year'] . "-" . $_GET['Month'] ."-01")); // first day of month
    echo $startRange . " to "; 
    $unix = strtotime($_GET['Year']."W".$week ."+1 week");
    while(date("m", $unix) == $_GET['Month']){ // keep looping/output of while it's correct month
        $endRange = date("d.m.Y", $unix-86400);
        echo $endRange . "</td>"; // Sunday of previous week

        //counting for Gold Room
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE (BookingDate>='".$startRange."' AND BookingDate<='".$endRange."') AND RoomID='77' ");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $count . "</td>";
        //end counting part

        //counting part Crystal Room
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE (BookingDate>='".$startRange."' AND BookingDate<='".$endRange."') AND RoomID='88' ");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
        echo "<td align='center'>" . $count . "</td>";
        //end counting part

       //counting part Diamond Room
       $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE (BookingDate>='".$startRange."' AND BookingDate<='".$endRange."') AND RoomID='99' ");
      $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
      echo "<td align='center'>" . $count . "</td>";
      //end counting part

      echo "</tr><tr> <td align='center'>";

      $lastStartRange = date("d.m.Y", $unix);
      echo $lastStartRange ." to "; // this week's monday
      $unix = $unix + (86400*7);
     }

   $lastEndRange = date("t.m.Y", strtotime($_GET['Year'] . "-" . $_GET['Month']));
   echo $lastEndRange; //echo last day of month
   ?>
   </td> <td align="center">
   <?php
   //counting for Gold Room
   $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE (BookingDate>='".$lastStartRange."' AND BookingDate<='".$lastEndRange."') AND RoomID='77' ");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $count . "</td>";
    //end counting part

    //counting part Crystal Room
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE (BookingDate>='".$lastStartRange."' AND BookingDate<='".$lastEndRange."') AND RoomID='88' ");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $count . "</td>";
    //end counting part

    //counting part Diamond Room
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE (BookingDate>='".$lastStartRange."' AND BookingDate<='".$lastEndRange."') AND RoomID='99' ");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $count . "</td>";
    //end counting part
  ?>
```

The problem with above code is that, when I choose the `month = January`, it will show a range of date 01.01.2017 - 31.12.2017. 
As for the record counting, it does not match with the record in the database table of `Reservation`. I have no idea how to simplify the code. Any suggestion or solution to my problem?

- The Month and Year for the date range is retrieved from `$_GET['Month']` and `$_GET['Year']`. The date range should change dynamically based on selected month and year..
- The date range is the range of week for any selected month, so there's no fixed range of week.
- The name of the room on the table header should be retrieved from
  database table 'Room'.
- The counting should count the number of booking for the particular room that is in the date range.

Thanks..

Comment: What is the logic/source behind your expected date ranges?

Comment: Weeks seem always starting Monday, with partials at either end the month as needed - my guess

Comment: I suggest you build a calendar table covering several years, one row per date, and you can include columns for other data such as week numbers if you want/need. This is going to make a reservation system a lot simpler to query imho

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen $week = date("W", strtotime($year . "-" . $month ."-01")); // weeknumber of first day of month

Echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($year . "-" . $month ."-01")) ." - "; // first day of month
$unix = strtotime($year."W".$week ."+1 week");
While(date("m", $unix) == $month){ // keep looping/output of while it's correct month

   Echo date("d/m/Y", $unix-86400) . "\n"; // Sunday of previous week
   Echo date("d/m/Y", $unix) ." - "; // this week's monday
   $unix = $unix + (86400*7);
}
Echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("last day of ".$year . "-" . $month)); //echo last day of month

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the date range is based on the number of week of a selected month..

Comment: You have two tables. And you wouldn't store room_name in the reservation table

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try building such following query

```
 SELECT '1.12.2017 - 3.12.2017', 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond,
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN '2017-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-03 23:59:59'
UNION 
SELECT '4.12.2017 - 10.12.2017', 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond,
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN '2017-12-04 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-10 23:59:59'
UNION
SELECT '11.12.2017 - 17.12.2017', 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond,
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN '2017-12-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-17 23:59:59'
UNION
SELECT '18.12.2017 - 24.12.2017', 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond,
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN '2017-12-18 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-24 23:59:59'
UNION 
SELECT '25.12.2017 - 31.12.2017 ', 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond,
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN '2017-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-31 23:59:59'
```

What you need is to build up such query using the desired parameters for the output. This way you will be able to get the output in a single shot. Now only issue here seems to be the RoomID and RoomName not looking dynamic. But the same, is what you will need to build it up in the query dynamically. So, if in case tomorrow, another room is added, it will show up in the query too.

Comment: but i need to make the date range change too, dynamically based on select option. the WHERE criteria should be according to the dynamic date range.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a calendar table (of at least date and weekno), so assuming this exists as a one row per date table:

```
select
   c.weekno, room.id, min(c.dt) startweek_dt, max(c.dt) endweek_dt, count(r.bookingdate)
from calendar_table c
cross join room
left join reservation r on c.caldate = r.bookingdate and room.id = r.room_id
where c.dt >= '2017-01-01' and c.dt < '2017-02-01'
group by week(c.weekno), room.id
```

Here is a [discussion on building a calendar table](https://www.brianshowalter.com/blog/calendar_tables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure instead of a query for dynamic binding of date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Reservation_data` (p_date1 date,p_date2 date)
BEGIN

SELECT concat(date_format(p_date1,'%d.%m.%Y'),' - ',date_format(p_date2,'%d.%m.%Y')), 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN p_date1 AND p_date2
UNION 
SELECT concat(date_format(p_date1,'%d.%m.%Y'),' - ',date_format(p_date2,'%d.%m.%Y')), 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate  BETWEEN p_date1 AND p_date2
UNION
SELECT concat(date_format(p_date1,'%d.%m.%Y'),' - ',date_format(p_date2,'%d.%m.%Y')), 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN p_date1 AND p_date2
UNION
SELECT concat(date_format(p_date1,'%d.%m.%Y'),' - ',date_format(p_date2,'%d.%m.%Y')), 
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN p_date1 AND p_date2
UNION 
SELECT concat(date_format(p_date1,'%d.%m.%Y'),' - ',date_format(p_date2,'%d.%m.%Y')),  
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 77 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 88 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Crystal,
        sum(CASE WHEN room_id = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dimond
FROM Reservations
WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN p_date1 AND p_date2;

END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerning about why the whole year is displayed when you selected Jan, that may be caused by your choice of using the week number to get date range.

The week number of the first day of year is 52 instead of 1. That may cause problem. There are many ways to get a specific date range. You could try another way to do this work.

Answer (score 0):

it's okay guys. I got the solution already. Thank you everyone for your effort.

Here is my answer

```
<table>
<thead>
    <td colspan="12"> <label>Month: </label>
        <select name="chooseMonth" onChange="location='?Month=' + this.value">
        <option value="1" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '1') { echo "selected"; } ?>>January</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '2') { echo "selected"; } ?>>February</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '3') { echo "selected"; } ?>>March</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '4') { echo "selected"; } ?>>April</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '5') { echo "selected"; } ?>>May</option>
        <option value="6" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '6') { echo "selected"; } ?>>June</option>
        <option value="7" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '7') { echo "selected"; } ?>>July</option>
        <option value="8" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '8') { echo "selected"; } ?>>August</option>
        <option value="9" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '9') { echo "selected"; } ?>>September</option>
        <option value="10" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '10') { echo "selected"; } ?>>October</option>
        <option value="11" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '11') { echo "selected"; } ?>>November</option>
        <option value="12" <?php if($_GET['Month'] == '12') { echo "selected"; } ?>>December</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Year: </label>
        <select name="chooseYear" onChange="location='?Month=<?php echo $_GET['Month']?>&Year=' + this.value">
        <option value="2013" <?php if($_GET['Year'] == '2013') { echo "selected"; } ?>>2013</option>
        <option value="2014" <?php if($_GET['Year'] == '2014') { echo "selected"; } ?>>2014</option>
        <option value="2015" <?php if($_GET['Year'] == '2015') { echo "selected"; } ?>>2015</option>
        <option value="2016" <?php if($_GET['Year'] == '2016') { echo "selected"; } ?>>2016</option>
        <option value="2017" <?php if($_GET['Year'] == '2017') { echo "selected"; } ?>>2017</option>
        <option value="2017" <?php if($_GET['Year'] == '2018') { echo "selected"; } ?>>2018</option>
        <option value="2017" <?php if($_GET['Year'] == '2019') { echo "selected"; } ?>>2019</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</thead>
<tr style="background-color: #ddd;">
    <th> Date </th>
    <?php 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE Status='T'", $mrrs);
        while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $RoomName = $rec['Room_Name'];
    ?>
        <td align="center"> <?php echo $RoomName; ?> </td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    <?php
    $endDate = date("t", strtotime($_GET['Year']."-".$_GET['Month']."-01"));

    $dayOfWeekOfFirstOfMonth = date("w", strtotime($_GET['Year']."-".$_GET['Month']."-01"));
    $lastDayOfFirstWeek = 8 - $dayOfWeekOfFirstOfMonth;

    $weeksArray = array(array("firstDay"=>1, "lastDay"=>$lastDayOfFirstWeek));

    $loopDate = $lastDayOfFirstWeek + 1;

    while($loopDate < $endDate)
    {
        $weeksArray[] = array("firstDay"=>$loopDate, "lastDay"=>($loopDate+6 > $endDate ? $endDate : $loopDate+6));
        $loopDate+=7;
    }

    foreach($weeksArray as $week)
    {
        $dayStart = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_GET['Year']."-".$_GET['Month']."-".$week["firstDay"]));
        $dayEnd = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($_GET['Year']."-".$_GET['Month']."-".$week["lastDay"]));

        echo $dayStart . "<br> to </br> " . $dayEnd . "</td>";

        //Rooms
        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE Status='T'", $mrrs);
        while ($rec2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
            $RoomID = $rec2['Id'];
            $RoomName = $rec2['Room_Name'];
            $num=0;
            echo "<td align='center'>";

            //counting start
            $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE (RoomID='".$RoomID."') AND (StartDate BETWEEN '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dayStart))."' AND '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dayEnd))."')",$mrrs);
            while ($rec3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
                $num++;
            } echo $num;
            //counting end

            echo "</td>";
        } //Rooms
        echo "</tr><tr><td align='center'>";
    }
?>
    </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the output:
[Link to the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5rK6.jpg)